# Which of these two different forms of spin-orbit interaction is correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, topological-insulators, calculus

I am seeing the spin-orbit interaction in two different ways:

1. $\lambda [\mathbf{p} \times \nabla V]\cdot \sigma$
2. $\lambda [\nabla V \times \mathbf{p}]\cdot \sigma$

I don't see how these two expressions can be equivalent though; in (1) there will be derivative operators from momentum acting on the gradient whereas in (2) this will not be the case.

Which one of these is correct?

Comment: Remember that the curl of a gradient is zero.

Comment: @ V. Rossetto I think you misunderstood Eq.1. Here $\mathbf{p}$ is an **operator** acting not only on the gradient but also on the single electron wavefunction, so Eq.1 is of course **not zero**.

Comment: @K-boy. Yes you are right, yet I haven't said that (1) is equal to zero. If you compute $\mathbf{p}\times\nabla V\psi$, you will get one term $(\nabla\times\nabla V)\psi$ (equal to zero) and *another* term $\nabla V\times\nabla \psi$, which happens to be (2).

Comment: @ V. Rossetto Yes. But (1) does *not* happens to be (2), they differ from each other by a **minus sign**.

Comment: @K-boy. Sure there's a minus sign.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that (times $\lambda$)

$$\vec{\nabla} V \times \vec{p} =-\vec{p} \times \vec{\nabla} V$$

Call $\vec{a} = \vec{\nabla} V \times \vec{p}$. You can check that:

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{\sigma}=(-\vec{a})\cdot\vec{\sigma}$$

Comment: but $\vec{p}$ is also an operator and proportional to $\vec{\nabla}$. So I would expect your RHS to be 0 (curl of grad is zero).

Comment: Could you please give us references to see the context?

Comment: @ BeauGeste The RHS in Nivalth's answer is *not* 0. Please see the other answer or the comments below the question for the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. In fact, you can check that $\triangledown V\times \mathbf{P}=-\mathbf{P}\times\triangledown V$. Here is the brief derivation:

$\mathbf{P}\times\triangledown V=(p_y\partial _zV-p_z\partial _yV,p_z\partial _xV-p_x\partial _zV,p_x\partial _yV-p_y\partial _xV)$. Let's take the first component $p_y\partial _zV-p_z\partial _yV$ for example, it's obvious that
$$p_y\partial _zV-p_z\partial _yV=-i\frac{\partial^2}{\partial _y\partial _z}V+\partial _zVp_y-(-i\frac{\partial^2}{\partial _z\partial _y}V+\partial _yVp_z)$$, 
but $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial _y\partial _z}V=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial _z\partial _y}V$, thus 
$$p_y\partial _zV-p_z\partial _yV=\partial _zVp_y-\partial _yVp_z$$. While the first component of $\triangledown V\times \mathbf{P}$ reads $\partial _yVp_z-\partial _zVp_y$, therefore we arrive at $\triangledown V\times \mathbf{P}=-\mathbf{P}\times\triangledown V$.

Comment: You proved that $\vec A\times\vec B=-\vec B\times\vec A$, which is true for vectors, but not for operators. Remember that, for instance, $\hat{\vec J}\times\hat{\vec J}$ is not the zero operator in quantum mechanics.

Comment: @ V. Rossetto I'm sorry that your comments are always ambiguous to me and they are more or less irrelevant to my point. Here I just proved that $\triangledown V\times \mathbf{p}$=$-\mathbf{p}\times \triangledown V$ for **operators**, that's all  !!!!!